# Doctrine is storing the wrong value in DB from a DateTime object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have the following entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

class Quote
{
    use SourceTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    private $quoteId;

    private $startDate;

    private $endDate;


    public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }


    public function setStartDate(\DateTime $startDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }


    public function setEndDate(\DateTime $endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
    }

}
```

and I have this method in the `QuoteRepository` class:

```
public function createQuoteHeader(Agreement $agreement): int
{
    $em      = $this->getEntityManager();
    $QuoteID = $this->getNewQuoteId();
    $year    = $agreement->getEndDate()->diff($agreement->getStartDate(), true)->y > 0
        ? $agreement->getEndDate()->diff($agreement->getStartDate(), true)->y
        : 0;

    dump($year);
    dump(gettype($year));
    dump($agreement->getEndDate());

    $entity = new Quote();
    ...
    $entity->setStartDate($agreement->getEndDate()->modify('+1 day'));
    dump($agreement->getStartDate());
    $entity->setEndDate($agreement->getEndDate()->modify("+1 day +{$year} year"));
    dump($agreement->getEndDate());
    ...

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $entity->getQuoteId();
}
```

The output from the `dump()` above are as follow (same order as in code):

```
0
"integer"
DateTime {#3005
  +"date": "2017-03-21 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
DateTime {#3004
  +"date": "2016-03-22 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
DateTime {#3005
  +"date": "2017-03-23 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Somehow the wrong values are being inserted in DB:

[image]

Maybe I am missing something but should not be `StartDate` equal to `2016-03-22 00:00:00`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through your code line by line.

```
$entity->setStartDate($agreement->getEndDate()->modify('+1 day'));
```

[`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) **mutates the `DateTime` object it is called upon**. 
This line added +1 day to `$agreement->getEndDate()` AND the **same** DateTime is passed to `$entity->setStartDate()`. So BOTH `$agreement->getEndDate()` and `$entity->getStartDate()` will return 2017-03-22!

```
dump($agreement->getStartDate());
```

You dumped the wrong date, hence 2016-03-22, masking the error. Should be `dump($entity->getStartDate());` and you would have noticed.

```
$entity->setEndDate($agreement->getEndDate()->modify("+1 day +{$year} year"));
```

Since `$agreement->getEndDate()` is now equal to 2017-03-22, +1 day +0 year will result in `$entity->getEndDate()` being equal to 2017-03-23.

I recommend using [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) to avoid all these unnecessary issues with object references.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the object you are trying to persist. You are getting the right result when you make dump(), but the datetime object is being modified later, so when you persist the object, all of the values get your last datetime result.
I recommend you to make "clone" in your datetime objects, and set the values separetely, something like this:

```
$oDatetime1  = clone($agreement->getEndDate());
$oDatetime2  = clone($agreement->getEndDate());

$entity->setStartDate($oDatetime1->modify('+1 day'));
$entity->setEndDate($oDatetime2->modify("+1 day +{$year} year"));
```